# JavaScript Canvas/fillStyle Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am currently developing a program called "Drive a Car" with my friend, where one car is controlled via WASD and the other is controlled with arrow keys. The problem is that the chassis color on the bottom car "function drawCar2()" seems to have a connection with the tires on the top car "function drawCar()", yet I cannot seem to find this connection. I even made two separate animation loops and tried to draw the tires in a different function. How can I fix this?

JSBin link: http://jsbin.com/yelojob/28/edit?html,css,js,output

drawCar functions:

```
function drawCar(x,y,angle,car1Color,wheel1Color) {

ctx.save();

ctx.translate(x,y);
ctx.rotate(angle);

//Chassis

ctx.fillStyle = car1Color;
ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 110, 25);

ctx.fill();

//Wheels

ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.fillStyle = wheel1Color;
  ctx.arc(75, 75, 15, 0, Math.PI, false);
  ctx.arc(135, 75, 15, 0, Math.PI, false);

  ctx.fill();

  //Windows

  ctx.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
  ctx.fillRect(120,25,5,25);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'darkorange'
  ctx.fillRect(153,55,7,10);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'darkred';
  ctx.fillRect(50,58,7,10);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(50,56,7,2);

  ctx.restore();

}

function drawCar2(x,y,angle,car2Color,wheel2Color) {

  ctx.save();

  ctx.translate(x,y);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  //Chassis

  ctx.fillStyle = car2Color;
  ctx.fillRect(50, 150, 110, 25);

  ctx.fill();

  //Wheels

  ctx.beginPath();

  ctx.fillStyle = wheel2Color;
  ctx.arc(75, 175, 15, 0, Math.PI, false);
  ctx.arc(135, 175, 15, 0, Math.PI, false);

  ctx.fill();

  //Windows

  ctx.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
  ctx.fillRect(120,125,5,25);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'darkorange'
  ctx.fillRect(153,155,7,10);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'darkred';
  ctx.fillRect(50,158,7,10);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
  ctx.fillRect(50,156,7,2);

  ctx.restore();

}
```

Comment: Could you please make a smaller project in which the same problem is demonstrated, without all the unrelated code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here it is condensed bare-bone: http://jsbin.com/cijoxil/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Never mind. I am the other person working on this project. I have Solved the issue, with some help from my counterpart. We no longer require assistance. Thank you for looking into the issue.